# Comparing variance for two games

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, variance

I saw this question here [Compare two coin tossing games](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874562/compare-two-coin-tossing-games) and wanted to figure it out myself, and I had some trouble with variance.

I can see easily that both games have expected value $\$500$. But my variance numbers make no sense to me.

1. $1000\text{Var}(X) = 1000(E[X^2] - E[X]^2) = 1000((\frac{1}{2}(\$1^2) + \frac{1}{2}(\$0^2)) - \$0.50^2) = \$250$
2. $\text{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = (\frac{1}{2}(\$1000^2) + \frac{1}{2}(\$0^2)) - \$500^2 = \$250000$

Is this right?

Comment: Would it help to note that the units of variance are (dollars squared).  If you take square roots to get the standard deviation, those units are dollars.

Comment: So the standard deviations are $\$15.81$ and $\$500$? Second one makes sense I suppose because you actually get either $\$0$ or $\$1000$ which means you deviate $\$500$ from the expected value of $\$500$ either way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your calculation is correct.  The second game has **much** higher variance than the first (although to be pedantic, the units of variance are not dollars, but dollars squared).

Intuitively, let's think about the distribution of possible outcomes of each game if both are played at the same expected value.  In the first case, the random total payout $X$ can be expressed as a function of a **binomial** random variable, which in turn is approximately **normally** distributed with mean $\mu = 500$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 250$.

On the other hand, in the second game, the random total payout is a function of a **Bernoulli** random variable, with $$\Pr[X = 1000] = \Pr[X = 0] = 1/2.$$

If we superimpose these probability mass functions atop each other, you can see what this looks like:

[image]

The blue "curve" is a plot of the first game's probability distribution; the orange lines represent the second game's probability distribution.  You can see that, for the first game, it is **virtually assured** (although not absolutely guaranteed) that your total payout will be somewhere between $450$ and $550$.  Indeed, the probability that it will **not** be in this narrow range is only $0.00139174$, and the chance that it will be less than $400$ or more than $600$ is **tiny**:  only about $1.80168 \times 10^{-10}$.

Yet, in the second game, the **only** outcomes are $0$ and $1000$, and there's a $50\%$ chance of either of these.  You can't even get any other result!  And because variance is a measure of central tendency--that is to say, the extent to which a random outcome will be observed far from its mean--we see why the second game has much higher variability than the first.

Comment: 1. How do you know the first is a binomial and the second is a Bernoulli? Is a binomial like multiple Bernoullis?

2. How do you plot the probability mass function of the first game? Second game is obvious due to the fact that there are only two outcomes but that blue curve is really interesting.

Comment: Also what software are you using to make that graph?

Comment: The sum $X = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$ of $n$ independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables with common probability of success $p$ is a binomial random variable with probability mass function $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}, \quad x = 0, 1, \ldots, n.$$  The blue curve is simply so dense, with $n = 1000$, that it appears as a continuous line.  The image was created in *Mathematica* 10.4.

Comment: Using what code/syntax? I do have Mathematica, it seems like it would be very valuable to know how to plot these things

Comment: `DiscretePlot[{PDF[BinomialDistribution[1000, 1/2], x], 
  PDF[BernoulliDistribution[1/2], x/1000]}, {x, 0, 1000}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]`